# Python multiprocessing PicklingError on code taken directly from the documentation

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, pickle

I am literally running the code directly from the python documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

```
from multiprocessing import Pool


def f(x):
    return x * x


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(5) as p:
        print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))
```

And I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3553, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-2-745c8e04055a>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/NAME/PycharmProjects/RLS-Features-IQP/test.py', wdir='C:/Users/NAME/PycharmProjects/RLS-Features-IQP')
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2022.1\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 198, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2022.1\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/NAME/PycharmProjects/RLS-Features-IQP/test.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))
  File "C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 268, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 657, in get
    raise self._value
  File "C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 431, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
  File "C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 206, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function f at 0x0000023F002A4678>: attribute lookup f on __main__ failed
```

I have tried everything from pathos multiprocessing, from pools to threads and I am out of ideas. What can I try next?

EDIT: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70947312/multiprocessing-in-pycharm-results-in-pickle-picklingerror

Comment: EDIT: PyCharm was the culprit. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70947312/multiprocessing-in-pycharm-results-in-pickle-picklingerror Details a solution

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 1):

From the attached output, I believe that the issue you are experiencing is due to `pickle`'s difficulty to serialize interactive functions.

Indirectly, this limitation is actually mentioned on the documentation page you have provided:

> **Note**: Functionality within this package requires that the **main** module be importable by the children. This is covered in Programming guidelines however it is worth pointing out here. This means that some examples, such as the multiprocessing.pool.Pool examples **will not work in the interactive interpreter.**

Saving this code in a Python file and running it using a standard interpreter should provide the results you are expecting.